# How to automaticaly delete images linked to a page after deleting the page?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I have an Annonce page with this model:

```
class AnnoncePage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Date de publication", blank=True, null=True)
    description = RichTextField(features=['h2', 'h3', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'hr', 'ol', 'ul'], blank=True)
    lieu = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    surface = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nb_pieces = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    prix_affiché_index = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)
    conditions_vente_et_prix = RichTextField(blank=True, features=['h2', 'h3', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'hr', 'ol', 'ul'])

    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
        FieldPanel('lieu', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('surface', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('nb_pieces', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('description', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('prix_affiché_index', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('conditions_vente_et_prix', classname="full")
    ]

    promote_panels = []
    settings_panels = []

    max_count = 20

class AnnoncePageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(AnnoncePage, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='gallery_images', null=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+', null=True
    )

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image')
    ]
```

How can I automaticaly delete the images of the Annonce page after deleting the Annonce page itself ? Do I need to change the model ?

Comment: Use `on_delete=models.CASCADE` on `AnnoncePageGalleryImage.page`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE

Comment: @allcaps Even with on_delete=models.CASCADE on AnnoncePageGalleryImage.page, the AnnoncePage images are still here after deleting AnnoncePage instance.

Comment: The database entries? Or the files on disk?

Comment: @allcaps In the database after deleting an AnnoncePage, annonce_annoncepagegalleryimage entries are deleted but wagttailimages_image entries are still here. Like there were no CASCADE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wagtail image object can be used in other places. Deleting those automagically might have nasty side effects for other content.

You can add a `delete` method to `AnnoncePage` or use a `pre_delete` signal. You need to iterate over all related gallery images and delete the related Wagtail images. Django leaves the file on disk, so you might want to handle that too.

```
class AnnoncePage(Page):
    ...
    def delete(self):
         for gallery_image in self.gallery_images.all():
              # Delete the file on disk here ...
              # After, delete the db obj.
              gallery_image.image.all().delete()
         self.gallery_images.all().delete()
         super().delete()
```

Disclaimer: untested code.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-delete
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete

Note that the `delete` method and `pre_delete` signal are not called on bulk actions. Your milage may vary.

Comment: Following your instructions I'm getting an error:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/pages/34/delete/
Exception Value: 'DeferringRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'delete'

Comment: `self.gallery_images.all().delete()`

Comment: `gallery_image.image.all().delete()`

Comment: Your new code succefully deleted images but it blocked the deletion of the AnnoncePage itself. So I added ` Page.objects.filter(id=self.id).delete()` too the delete method. Now it working as I want, thank you

Comment: Great! We should call super. That executes the delete method on the Page class.